# Getting html data from template generated list - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, dom

I am generating a list from a template engine (Template7) and adding a userID to the data tag in each list item. For example

```
<li>
    <a id='user' data-user-id='5'>
        <div>content here</div>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a id='user' data-user-id='6'>
        <div>content here</div>
    </a>
</li>
```

I am trying to get the "user-id" data of the list item clicked on using jQuery, but what I seem to be doing instead is getting the user-id of the first list item - in this case always 5.

```
$(document).on("touchend", "#user", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var userItem = $("#user");
    var userID = userItem.data("user-id");
    console.log(matchID);
});
```

Where am I going wrong? A unique ID for each item would work, but then it would need to be parsed etc so there must be a better way! Is there a best practice for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing #user with this should work in your case

Id selector always selects first element with matching Id. it is advisable not to have multiple element with same id. try to use class name instead.
any ways for your query you can use below code.

```
$(document).on("touchend", "#user", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var userID = $(this).data("user-id");
        console.log(userID);
    });
```

Comment: '$("#user").on("touchend", function(e) {         and      var userID = $(this).data("user-id");'

Tried this, doesn't seem to be working either!

Comment: the console.log is never reached now

Comment: no error. Interestingly, using 'var userID = $(this).data("user-id");' but an id=user instead of class=user works exactly as wanted, but like you have mentioned an id should be unique so I do not understand why this works!

Comment: id should be unique because when you select $('#user') it will always return first element. this is exactly how your code was initially.

now with updates that I gave we are no more using id selector so here we point our element based on this which is current element. 

also I checked in browser by replacing touch end with click it works for me.
if still you see an issue please replace touch end with click and check if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a css class on each anchor item, like this:

```
 <li>
    <a class='user' data-user-id='5'>
        <div>content here</div>
    </a>
</li>
```

Id attributes are meant to be unique to that element.

Comment: the console.log line is never reached now, not sure what is going on!

Answer (score 1):

```
To get the content of the attribute **data-user-id** like in <a id='user' data-user-id='5'> you have to use

$(this).attr("data-user-id") // will return the string "5"

or .data() (if you use newer jQuery >= 1.4.3)

$(this).data("user-id") // will return the number 5
```